# A way to clean up laravel

Tags: laravel

By default `laravel` is huge.

Its a way to clean up only needed depencies?

For sample, when i'm installing laravel, some default configs are provided. I dont need the API Routes or other, when i'm using the normal web-routes.

Comment: well, everything is used. if you want a lite version.. use `lumen` or go down to `symfony` or even.. VanillaPHP. though personally i'd left those are unused there, because laravel internally will be looking for them and throws exception in case they dont exists.

Comment: I think that specific api.php file in the routes should bother you. Honestly, if you want a lighter edition you may use Lumen as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to don't want to load  API route you can simply comment out this line in `RouteServiceProvider`

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes(); //comment this line

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    //
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To make Laravel leaner, another good approach is to have a look on your ServiceProviders, which are loaded in `config/app.php`. Just deactivate all ServiceProvider you don't need and test your application.

ServiceProviders can also be loaded from packages. So take also attention to loaded packages through your `composer.json`.